# For loop wont start at negative

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

So I need to make an array which I can reference, from [-2:25]. If I start at 0 the code works just fine, but I need to perform a low pass filter so I need the -2 and -1 values of x(n) as well and I need to be able to reference it like A[-2]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
int main(void)
{
    int N=25;          //Setting Number of Iterations
    int i;              //Initializing Variables
    double xn;  //
    double hn;
    double A[27];

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("data3.txt","w");      //Save to File

    do { i=-2;i<N;i++;

    { xn = 2*exp(-0.01*i)*sin(0.2*i);
        A[i] = xn;}
    } while (i>0);

     (i=0;i<N;i++)      //For loop for i=
    {
        xn = 2*exp(-0.01*i)*sin(0.2*i);
        A[i] = xn;
        fprintf(fp,"%d\t%f\t%f\n",i,xn,A[i]); //Saving results to File
         printf("xn= %d\t%f\n",i, A[i]);


    }
    printf("xn1 = %f\n", A[1]);
    printf("xn5 = %f\n", A[5]);



    return(0);
```

Comment: What happened to `for` in your "for loop"? Also, what is this supposed to mean: `do { i=-2;i<N;i++;`?

Answer (score 4):

This makes little sense. `A[-2]` is undefined behavior. Trying to assign to it probably overwrites other variables. If `A` has 27 elements the indices are 0 - 26. Use `A[i+2]` wherever you have `A[i]` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a pointer, and you can do `p - 2` just fine. However, you need to manage your indexes carefully.

What I'd suggest you do is create two variables. The first is your array A. Size it to be the number of elements, not the indexes: if your range is -2 to 25, then that should be an array of length 27 (25 - -2).

Then, create a second variable P, which would be:

```
double *P = &A[2];
```

Then you can do `P[-2]`, which would point to the address of A[0].

Comment: Typo: Unless I'm missing some really cool trick, you left out the `*` here `double P = &A[2];`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I fixed the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Learn your loop constructions. Equivalently:

```
// (init; break condition; step)
for (i = ...; i < N; ++i) {
    ... // do stuff
}

int i = ...; // init
if(i < N) { // initial check (may be unnecessary by construction)
    do {
        ... // do stuff
        ++i; // step
    } while(i < N); // break condition
}

int i = ...; // init
while(i < N) { // break condition
    ... // do stuff
    ++i; // step
}
```